# В поисковой выдаче в ссылке на сайт отображается надпись MODX Revolution

Tags: modx

Всем здравствуйте! Только начал разбираться с MODX, поэтому прошу строго не судить за возможно глупый вопрос. Как можно убрать надпись MODX Revolution в заголовке в ссылке поисковой выдачи? Вот картинка.[image: вот эта приписка MODX Revolution]
Подскажите хотя бы направление где ковырять, уже всю голову сломал.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте настройки вашего сайта по адресу `https://вашсайт.ru/manager/?a=system/settings` и посмотрите настройку `site_name`, там по умолчанию значение `MODX Revolution`, исправьте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, нашел эту настройку, там убрано значение по умолчанию, стоит название сайта. Где еще можно посмотреть?

Comment: Тогда вам надо посмотреть, как у страницы формируется содержимое html тега head, для указанной страницы ищите шаблон, вероятно есть чанк внутри, который формирует содержимое тега <title></title> Вот здесь нужно править, смотря что там -сниппет, чанк или просто текст.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: @ЖмыхПожилой очень рад! Отметьте ответ как решение.